# how to make this if else in ternary operator

Tags: php

I am looking for email in my view page. there are two ways email can get there. Either by POST or by SESSION.
if it is a $_POST then I want to use the $_POST email other wise I want to use the email saved in session.
Currently the code I have is below

```
$email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : '');
```

whats the BEST way to do it in least lines of code

Comment: Just a note that best usually does not equal least lines of code. While shorter programs can often be better, your goal should be to write efficient and maintainable code. Part of maintainability is readability, which is typically in direct opposition least lines of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're just looking for this (assuming the email address is stored in the `$_SESSION` array under the key `email`):

```
$email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : $_SESSION['email']);
```

Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Note that `$email` will be `NULL` instead of the empty string if neither of these values is set. Also, if the session variable is not set, this will produce a warning under the default configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$email = (isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : (isset($_SESSION['email'])) ? $_SESSION['email'] : '');
```

Which is the same of:

```
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
    if(isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
        $email = $_SESSION['email'];
    } else {
        $email = '';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A funny alternative to the correct answer of @Gabriel Santos

```
$input = function($param, $default = '') {
    static $input;

    if (null === $input) {
        $input = array_merge($_SESSION, $_POST);
    }

    return isset($input[$param]) ? $input[$param] : $default;
};


// get input
$email = $input('asd');
```